# Perl XML::DOM::Parser

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xmldom

I'm trying to get som information from a RSS feed usin perl, XML::DOM and XML::Parser.
I'm having a hard time getting som documentation on XML::DOM and XML::Parser :(

This is the rss feed outlay.

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>The title numer 1</title>
        <link>
        http://www.example.com/link1.php?getfile=1&sha=1234567890
        </link>
        <description>
        File 1
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>The title numer 2</title>
        <link>
        http://www.example.com/link1.php?getfile=2&sha=0192837465
        </link>
        <description>
        File 2
        </description>
    </item>
        <item>
        <title>The title numer 3</title>
        <link>
        http://www.example.com/link1.php?getfile=1&sha=0987654321
        </link>
        <description>
        File 3
        </description>
    </item>
</channel>
```

So I'm trying to get the 'title' and the 'link' from this rss feed.

I can't use XML::LibXML or XML::simple or XML::RSS

Answer (score 1):

I get errors trying to install it, but it looks like it would be something like:

```
use XML::DOM::Parser qw( );
use XML::XQL         qw( );
use XML::XQL::DOM    qw( );

my $parser = XML::DOM::Parser->new();
my $doc = $parser->parsefile("file.xml");

for my $item_node ($doc->xql('/channel/item')) {
   my $title = join '', $item_node->xql('title/textNode()');
   my $link  = join '', $item_node->xql('link/textNode()');
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with parsing your RSS XML file. For file

```
<xml>
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>The title numer 1</title>
        </item>

    <item>
        <title>The title numer 2</title>
        </item>
</channel>
</xml>
```

You can do

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Parser;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::DOM::Lite qw(Parser XPath);

my $parser = Parser->new();
my $doc = $parser->parseFile('2.xml', whitespace => 'strip');


#XML::DOM::Lite::NodeList - blessed array ref for containing Node objects
my $nlist = $doc->selectNodes('/xml/channel/item/title');


foreach my $node (@{$nlist})
{
    print $node->firstChild()->nodeValue() . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your XML data (unquoted '&' character):

Lines such as

```
...getfile=1&sha...
```

must be written as

```
...getfile=1&amp;sha...
```

Once this is fixed, you can use XML::Reader:PP to parse the XML:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Reader::PP;

my $rdr = XML::Reader::PP->new(\*DATA, { mode => 'branches' },
  { root => '/rss/channel/item', branch => [ '/title', '/link' ] });

while ($rdr->iterate) {
    my ($title, $link) = $rdr->value;

    for ($title, $link) {
        $_ = '' unless defined $_;
    }

    print "title = '$title'\n";
    print "link  = '$link'\n";
}

__DATA__
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
        <title>The title numer 1</title>
        <link>
        http://www.example.com/link1.php?getfile=1&amp;sha=1234567890
        </link>
        <description>
        File 1
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>The title numer 2</title>
        <link>
        http://www.example.com/link1.php?getfile=2&amp;sha=0192837465
        </link>
        <description>
        File 2
        </description>
    </item>
        <item>
        <title>The title numer 3</title>
        <link>
        http://www.example.com/link1.php?getfile=1&amp;sha=0987654321
        </link>
        <description>
        File 3
        </description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```